# Previous Build Number in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have a batch Job (not the pipeline Job) in Jenkins where I am using a plugin called "Naginator" which will check if the current build is failed/unstable - If the current build is failed/unstable it will run immediately the next build to confirm the error is genuine.  If the error is not genuine then the run is successful and it will periodically set the next build to run.  Along with this, I use some CMD commands to move my data into another folder with the Build number as my folder name.

Now here is the issue, if the previous build was unstable and Naginator runs the next build and that build is stable then what I need to do is delete the previous unstable build data from the folder manually.  Is it possible to fetch the previous build number in Jenkins so that I can delete the file in an automated way - lets say in CMD Commands .BAT file.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has it's own global variables. You can check whem in your pipeline job -> Pipeline Syntax -> Global Variables Reference.

Additionally check http://jenkins_url:port/env-vars.html/

For your purpose `BUILD_NUMBER` exist.

Just create new env var like this:

```
PREV_BUILD_NUMBER = $($BUILD_NUMBER -1)
```

Excuse me if this piece of code will not work, I'm not good about scripting) Just for example.

UPDATE:

also you can find in mentioned reference a list of variables:

- previousBuild
- previousBuildInProgress
- previousBuiltBuild
- previousCompletedBuild
- previousFailedBuild
- previousNotFailedBuild
- previousSuccessfulBuild